How can handle onPaginationChanged callback in Ag-grid react?
I am using Ag-grid react. and looking for getting current page number and then send request to server according to the current page value. The pagination component is also, a custom pagination component.
As you can see in the following code, when i define a function callback as value for onPaginationChanged, the function calls infinitely!. How can prevent this behaviour?.
"use strict";

import React, {
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useState,
  StrictMode,
} from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css";
import {
  ColDef,
  ColGroupDef,
  GridApi,
  GridOptions,
  GridReadyEvent,
  createGrid,
} from "ag-grid-community";
import { IOlympicData } from "./interfaces";

const GridExample = () => {
  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: "100%", height: "100%" }), []);
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: "100%", width: "100%" }), []);
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<IOlympicData[]>();
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
    {
      field: "athlete",
      minWidth: 170,
      checkboxSelection: true,
      headerCheckboxSelection: true,
    },
    { field: "age" },
    { field: "country" },
    { field: "year" },
    { field: "date" },
    { field: "sport" },
    { field: "gold" },
    { field: "silver" },
    { field: "bronze" },
    { field: "total" },
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      editable: true,
      filter: true,
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 100,
    };
  }, []);

  const onGridReady = useCallback((params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    fetch("https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data: IOlympicData[]) => setRowData(data));
  }, []);

  const getUser = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Caaled");
    fetch("https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data: IOlympicData[]) => setRowData(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div style={gridStyle} className={"ag-theme-quartz-dark"}>
        <AgGridReact<IOlympicData>
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          suppressRowClickSelection={true}
          groupSelectsChildren={true}
          rowSelection={"multiple"}
          onPaginationChanged={getUser}
          pagination={true}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <GridExample />
  </StrictMode>
);

